# Shift+Alt+Left Mouse не работает. Blender 2.81

Tags: blender, hotkeys

```
    No LSB modules are available.
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
    Release:    18.04
    Codename:   bionic
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Blender 2.81.** У меня работает сочетание <kbd>Alt</kbd> + **Left Mouse** , но когда я хочу выделить еще раз подобным образом и при этом не удаляя уже существующее выделение через <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + **Left Mouse**, то меняется раскладка, все выделение пропадает и выделяется только одна вершнина (ну или ребро или грань). Хотя другие сочетания с <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> работают( например <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> )[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня так и не получилось исправить это в Gnome 3. Я сделал на <kbd>Alt</kbd> + ***Left Mouse*** добавление к выделению по умолчанию (т.е. поменял местами <kbd>Alt</kbd> + ***Left Mouse*** и <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  ***Left Mouse***)

В принципе удобно, нужно только не забывать сбрасывать выделение когда нужно

Понимаю, что это не совсем ответ на вопрос, однако это мой walkaround

Comment: Такое детское решение)) Не думал, что обычная перестановка поможет. Большое спасибо))

Answer (score 1):

В твиках к гному у вас наверняка стоит переключение раскладки на alt + shift
После того, как я убрал эту возможность, стало всё норм работать
попробуйте..